# ZK Time and Attendance device with PHP

Tags: php, apache, live, static-ip-address

I am using [ZKlib][1]

[1]: https://github.com/dnaextrim/php_zklib to connect to my ZK time and attendance machine. It is using UDP/SOAP to connect to device. Everything is working fine on localhost. But when I live it on server and try to access it though my public static ip that I have purchased from my ISP, even though I have port forwarded it, it cannot connect to the device. I have no issues in connecting to my IP cam through same router. 
Another interesting fact is that if I make 3g Hotspot from my cellphone and connect my laptop to it. Now when I put public static IP of my router from which device is connected, and try to hit the device, Wow! Device is connected. But same application when I live it on server, even though I am on my 3g connection it could not connect to my device though my router that is port forwarded. I am wondering what is the issue with it when I live it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved it. It was issue with my host server. I had to talk to them to enable php_socket.dll extension on their server. Now it's running fine.

Comment: I have enabled the extension. But still its not working. Can anyone help me please

Comment: Which models have SOAP support?